# Python/selenium: How could it be possible that I got the same items from different pages? What's wrong with page_source?

Tags: python

1. import packages

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   import requests
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   import re
   ```
2. open 'taobao.com' (a Chinese website similar to Amazon) and search for 'iphone'

   ```
   browser=webdriver.Chrome()
   browser.get('https://www.taobao.com')
   a=browser.find_element_by_id('q')#find the input box
   a.send_keys('iphone')#search for iphone
   button=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-button')#the button
   button.click()
   ```
3. Let r1,r2 refers to page 1,2 respectively and get stall, price and title.

   ```
   #=============================================
   title1=[]
   price1=[]
   stall1=[]
   title2=[]
   price2=[]
   stall2=[]
   c=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.input.J_Input')#the page input box
   c.clear()
   c.send_keys(1)#input the page you want to jump to 
   d=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.J_Submit')#the button
   d.click()
   r1=browser.page_source#r1 refers to the source code of page 1
   title1=re.findall('\"raw_title\":\"(.*?)\"',r1,re.S)
   price1=re.findall('\"view_price\":\"(.*?)\"',r1,re.S)
   stall1=re.findall('user_id.*?\"nick\":\"(.*?)\"',r1,re.S)
   #=============================================
   c=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.input.J_Input')
   c.clear()
   c.send_keys(2)
   d=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.J_Submit')
   d.click()
   r2=browser.page_source#r2 refers to the source code of page 2
   title2=re.findall('\"raw_title\":\"(.*?)\"',r2,re.S)
   price2=re.findall('\"view_price\":\"(.*?)\"',r2,re.S)
   stall2=re.findall('user_id.*?\"nick\":\"(.*?)\"',r2,re.S)
   #==================================
   r1==r2# compare r1 and r2
   price1==price2
   title1==title2
   stall1==stall2
   ```
4. the outcome is unbelievable and confusing.

   ```
    r1==r2# compare r1 and r2

   Out[94]: False

   price1==price2

   Out[95]: True

   title1==title2

   Out[96]: True

   stall1==stall2

   Out[97]: True
   ```
5. If r1 ≠r2, then how could price1=price2?  stall1=stall2? 
   I guess there is sth wrong with page_source. But I don't know what's it and how to correct it.
   Thanks for your help! I've been confused for a long time.

Comment: Maybe dynamic content on the page like "suggestions" or "ads" thats are different every time?
Sounds like a normal page behaviour for me. A sourcecode is rarely always the same on modern pages

Comment: I have jumped to page 2 and use 'r=browser.page_source' to get the current source code. But it seems that I got the souce code of page 1 rather page 2. I am not curious about why r1≠r2. They should be different  of course bexause of dynamic content.  I don't why i got the source code of page 1. 
I have already jumped to page 2！

Comment: ok. In your question you did not say anything about r2 being the source code of page 1. Does the code wait for the page to finish loading before fetching `r2`? If yes, did you really check that?

Comment: I guess r2 got page1's source code because the data from r1  and r2 are the same.  that's just my guest and I think it's closed to the truth.  But I am really confused that if r2 got sourcecode of page 1 then how can I got that of page 1 's？The problem is that I have already jumped to page 2 then use 'r2=browser.page_source' to get the current source code? I am not sure if r2 gets page 1 's source code while I am quite sure that r2 is not the source code of page 2 because some text of source code of page 2 from Chrome directly can't be found in r2's content.